# Rspec test in rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am newbie in rspec test.

I have a file **/spec/models/class_spec.rb**. The content of the file is

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Class, :type => :model do
  #pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
  before(:each) do
    @my_class=Factory.create(:class, params)
  end
end
```

I also have a **/spec/rails_helper** file. When I run rspec in command line

```
command : rspec spec/models/class_spec.rb
```

I gets the following error

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/airbrake-ruby-1.4.4/lib/airbrake-ruby.rb:102:in `configure': the 'default' notifier was already configured (Airbrake::Error)
from /home/akhil/test-prjct/ver3/this_prjct/config/initializers/errbit.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
```

Can someone tell me about issue and also give a link to a tutorial for learning to write test codes using rspec. Thanks in advance

My gem list is

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rails-erd"
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

errbit.rb file has following content

```
Airbrake.configure do |config|
   config.host = 'https://192.168.2.143:3000'
   config.project_id = -1
   config.project_key = '76068df1155420d2658i35a75o95gk26'
   config.environment = Rails.env
   config.ignore_environments = %w(development test)
end
```

Comment: what's in this file? `config/initializers/errbit.rb`

Comment: I have added errbit.rb also. Please check it

Comment: Rails.application.initialize! command in environment.rb is loading files twice in the initializer and also routes.rb .I found its not the issue of errbit.rb . Issue occured as Airbrake is configured twice(as I said all files in initailizer is loading twice)